# After_destroy doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have 2 models: Post and AuditLog, they are not associated with each other, and I want to trigger an action on AudiLog model after a Post has been deleted. I also have other callbacks in Post model that happen on AuditLog model after a Post is saved and `after_save` works fine but `after_destroy` does not.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save    :confirm_audit_log, if: :submitted?
  after_destroy :say_goodbye

  private

  def confirm_audit_log
    audit_log = AuditLog.where(user_id: self.user_id, 
                start_date: (self.date - 7.days..self.date)).last
    audit_log.confirmed! if audit_log
  end

  def say_goodbye
    "Goodbye!"
  end
end
```

So after I delete a post I should see "Goodbye" but when I do

```
Post.last.destroy
```

The post instance is deleted from the database but the callback is not called. Can you please explain to me why?

UPDATE:
I have changed to this metod in after_destroy:

```
def unconfirm_audit_log
  audit_log = AuditLog.where(user_id: self.user_id, 
              start_date: (self.date - 7.days..self.date)).last
  audit_log.pending!
end
```

and it's never called. I have tried putting debugger inside of the uncofirm_audit_log method and it does not even reach there.

Comment: What version of rails and ruby are you using?

Comment: 'So after I delete a post I should see "Goodbye"' - You are not printing the "Goodbye" text, just returning it from the method. Try `puts "Goodbye"` instead.

Comment: Did you add `after_destroy :unconfirm_audit_log` to the model `Post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `after_destroy` to `before_destroy`. I think you will get nil in `self` because object is destroyed.

So try below code:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save    :confirm_audit_log, if: :submitted?
  before_destroy :unconfirm_audit_log

  private

  def confirm_audit_log
    audit_log = AuditLog.where(user_id: self.user_id, 
                start_date: (self.date - 7.days..self.date)).last
    audit_log.confirmed! if audit_log
  end

  def unconfirm_audit_log
    audit_log = AuditLog.where(user_id: self.user_id, 
              start_date: (self.date - 7.days..self.date)).last
    audit_log.pending!
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that did it! You are a genius :))) I am still learning how callbacks work in Rails. Thank you ever so much for your help!!!